# Required String parameter 'surname' is not present

Tags: java, spring-boot, curl

Here is a part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPerson", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void addPerson(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("surname") String surname){
        //...
    }
```

Here is my cURL:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/addPerson?name=John&surname=Doe
```

Request fails:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-10-02T06:10:48.172+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required String parameter 'surname' is not present","path":"/addPerson"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by putting URL in quotes:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/addPerson?name=John&surname=Doe"
```